# how to check whether items present in list box & how to check list box has duplicates? in csharp

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
       }
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string val = listBox1.Text.Trim();
            if (listBox1.Items.Contains(val)) {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no items present");
            }
        }
```

elements are entered from text box to list box, If entered the same data,. how to check? or msg box should display and
    while deleting items from the list box if there is no items how to i get to know.

Comment: Here are your problems, you question has little detail, who knows what this is, winforms, wpf, mvc, you have shown no code, you have shown no attempt. please read the help on asking a question [ask]

Comment: Please some code snippet, what are you trying to accomplish via code

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value entered in the textbox is already in the listbox or not:

```
bool listContainsItem = Listbox.Items.Any(item => item.Value == textboxValue);

if(listContainsItem)
{
  // ... item is in listbox, do your magic
}
else
{
  // ... item is not in listbox, do some other magic 
}
```

You can do this in the Onchange event of your textbox, or when clicking a button, ... give us more context so we can provide you a better solution.

Comment: Listbox.Items.Any(item => item.Value == textboxValue); can you please explain about this.

Comment: Any() is used to determine whether a sequence contains any elements or not. So you can "iterate" over each "item" and check if it's value (listbox item value) is the same or not compairing to your textbox value. References: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HashSet` as data source to make sure your list contains unique elements.

In example :

```
HashSet<string> ListBoxSource = new HashSet<string>();

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string val = listBox1.Text.Trim();
    // ListBoxSource.Add(val) Return true if val isn't present and perform the adding
    if (ListBoxSource.Add(val))
    {
        // DataSource needs to be a IList or IListSource, hence the conversion to List
        listBox1.DataSource = ListBoxSource.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item is already in list");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check for duplicated item by looping through each item in the list to be compared with name of item to be added when add button is clicked:

```
    private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool similarItem = false;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemText.Text.Trim()))
        {
            foreach (string listItem in itemListBox.Items)
            {
                if (listItem == itemText.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Similar item detected");
                    similarItem = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!similarItem)
                itemListBox.Items.Add(itemText.Text);
        }
    }
```

To prompt user when delete button is clicked when there is no item, the selected index will be -1, u may use that as the condition to prompt user:

```
    private void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (itemListBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
            itemListBox.Items.RemoveAt(itemListBox.SelectedIndex);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No item exist in the list box, operation fail");
    }
```

Comment: if we didn't select the item and clicked the delete button it shows "No item exist in the list box, operation fail" how we can get this out?

Comment: From what you said, u mean u would like user to delete item by entering item name in textbox then only delete it instead of by selecting the item & delete them via button, is that true?